# How to merge two datasets from different workspaces in Roboflow?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, project, yolo, roboflow

I have two projects in Roboflow, each in a different workspace, and I want to merge the datasets from these two projects into a single dataset. What is the best way to do this in Roboflow?

I have tried downloading the datasets from each project and manually merging them, but this is a time-consuming process, especially if I need to update the merged dataset later on. Is there a way to merge datasets directly within Roboflow, or automate the process of merging the datasets?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to export the dataset from one workspace in COCO JSON format. Be sure the generated version has no augmentation applied and no preprocessing other than Auto-Orient.

From here, unzip the exported files and import them to the new project.

If they were in the same workspace, then this option would’ve been available: https://docs.roboflow.com/merge-datasets

I want to add, you also have the option to clone the images to the other workspace if it is a public project: https://blog.roboflow.com/use-open-source-computer-vision-datasets/